# ModuleError on bat file running python script

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I am having trouble running a python script from the windows scheduler, so I am looking to schedule a bat file that runs the script which outputs to a log file.

However, the bat file gives me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ibapi`. `ibapi` is a module folder that is contained in `C:\TWS API\source\pythonclient`. I tried the below bat code, but it doesn't work. How do I get rid of this `ModuleNotFoundError`?

```
setlocal
set PYTHONPATH="C:\TWS API\source\pythonclient"
set PYTHONPATH="C:\TWS API\samples\Python\PEAD"
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe "C:\TWS API\samples\Python\PEAD\LiveScraper.py" %*
endlocal
```

Comment: Does `python.exe "C:\TWS API\samples\Python\PEAD\LiveScraper.py" %*
endlocal` work from the command line?

Comment: Not a batch file error. That is a python error.